# Get child element using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to get input with class `end` when the value of class `start` is changed.

Also I can have more than 1 `end` and `start` class

```
<tr class="input-proporsional">
   <td>1. Start -</td>
   <td>
   <input type="text" name="start[]" class="form-control start" style="width: 60px"> // when the value is changed 
</td>
   <td>End -</td>
   <td>
   <input type="text" name="end[]" class="form-control end" style="width: 60px"> // get this input
</td>
   <td>Rate</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="rate[]" class="form-control rate" style="width: 90px"></td>
</tr>

<tr class="input-proporsional">
   <td>2. Start -</td>
   <td>
   <input type="text" name="start[]" class="form-control start" style="width: 60px"> 
</td>
   <td>End -</td>
   <td>
   <input type="text" name="end[]" class="form-control end" style="width: 60px">
</td>
   <td>Rate</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="rate[]" class="form-control rate" style="width: 90px"></td>
</tr>
```

So far, I've tried something like code bellow:

```
$(".start").on("change", function() {
  let element = $(this).parent().parent().find('td').children('end').html();
  console.log(element);
}
```

But still not working, it return `undefined` into console.
And if write my code like this (up to `tr` parent):

```
console.log($(this).parent().parent().html());
```

The result is like this (I got all of the td):

```
<td>1. Start -</td>
<td><input type="text" name="start[]" class="form-control start" style="width: 60px"></td>
<t>End -</td>
<td><input type="text" name="end[]" class="form-control end" style="width: 60px"></td>
<td>Rate</td>
<td><input type="text" name="rate[]" class="form-control rate" style="width: 90px"></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will have to use [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
$(".start").on("change", function() {
  let element = $(this).closest('tr').find('.end').html();
  console.log(element);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use `parents` like:

```js
$(".start").on("change", function() {
  let element = $(this).parents("tr").find(".end");
  console.log(element)
});
```